# Random variable defined on the IID

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value, variance, sampling

I understand that the mean and variance of the Cauchy distribution is undefined. I also understand that if we try to take independent and identically distributed random variable from the Cauchy distribution and attempt to use the Central Limit Theorem, it doesn't work. But what about the following case:

Let $X_1,X_2,X_3$ be independent and identical random variables from the Cauchy distribution ($x_0,\gamma$). Define
$$Y=median(X_1,X_2,X_3)$$
Is it possible to find the expectation and variance of $Y$? If so, how? If not, is it because of the fundamental fact that the central limit theorem cannot be applied to the Cauchy distribution?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: I suspect that Y has a mean (of $x_0$) but not a finite variance.  Meanwhile I suspect that if you considered $Z=median(X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4,X_5)$ then $Z$ would have a finite mean and variance.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit further on why this would be the case?

Comment: $$\{Y>t\} \subseteq \{X_1>t, X_2>t\} \cup \{X_1>t, X_3>t\} \cup \{X_2>t, X_3>t\}$$ and so $P[Y>t] \leq 3 P[X_1>t]^2$ and so $E[Y^+] = \int_0^{\infty}P[Y>t]dt < \infty$

Comment: Handwaving, the median concentrates the distribution in a way related to a symmetric Beta distribution.  Empirically looking at a standard Cauchy, $E[|Y|]$ looks as if it might be about $1.069$, which would make $E[Y]=0$ by symmetry but $E[Y^2]$ does not seem to converge; meanwhile $E[|Z|]$ looks as if it might be about $0.6913$, which would make $E[Z]=0$ by symmetry and $E[Z^2]$ seems  to be about $1.215$.

Comment: Thanks for both of your comments. However, probability is not my strong suite and I am having a hard time keeping up. Would it be possible to be a bit more exhaustive in the explanation? Like what is t and how is the upper bound established relates to Y and Z?

Comment: The argument in my comment holds for any real number $t$.  It says that $Y>t$ only when at least two of the random variables are larger than $t$.  The argument implies that for a Cauchy that is symmetric about zero, there is a finite mean for $Y$.  By symmetry the mean is zero. So any shifted Cauchy (shifted by $x_0$) also has a finite mean (of $x_0$) which validates the first part of Henry's comment.

Comment: Are there any resources where I can read a bit more about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer expands my comment and validates Henry's first comment. Let $X_1, X_2, X_3$ be i.i.d. Cauchy with symmetry about 0 (so $x_0=0$). Define $Y$ as the median.

Fix $t\in \mathbb{R}$.  The median is bigger than $t$ if and only if at least two of the random variables are larger than $t$:
$$ \{Y>t\} = \{X_1>t, X_2>t\} \cup \{X_1>t, X_3>t\} \cup \{X_2>t, X_3>t\}$$
So by the union bound and symmetry:
$$ P[Y>t] \leq 3P[X_1>t, X_2>t] = 3P[X_1>t]^2$$
where the final equality holds by independence of $X_1$ and $X_2$.
Write $Y = Y^+ - Y^-$ where $Y^+=\max[Y,0]$ and $Y^-=\max[-Y,0]$. We get
\begin{align}
Y^+ &= \int_0^{\infty} 1\{Y>t\}dt \\
\implies E[Y^+] &= \int_0^{\infty} P[Y>t]dt \\
&\leq 3 \int_0^{\infty} P[X_1>t]^2dt \\
&< \infty
\end{align}
So $E[Y^+]$ is finite.  By symmetry we know $E[Y^-]=-E[Y^+]$ and so $E[Y]$ exists and is 0.

To show infinite variance we notice:
$$ \{X_1>t, X_2>t\} \subseteq \{Y>t\}$$
So $$P[X_1>t]^2 \leq P[Y>t]$$
Now
$$ (Y^+)^2 = 2\int_0^{\infty} t 1\{Y>t\}dt $$
So
\begin{align}
E[(Y^+)^2] &= 2\int_0^{\infty} t P[Y>t]dt\\
&\geq 2 \int_0^{\infty} t P[X_1>t]^2dt = \infty
\end{align}
So $E[(Y^+)^2]= \infty$.  Thus, $Y$ has mean 0 but infinite variance.

If we consider shifting $Y$ (so we have Cauchy with $x_0\neq 0$) then the mean shifts to $x_0$ but the variance stays infinite.    You can validate Henry's last comment on $Z$ being the median of 5 i.i.d. Cauchy using a similar technique.

Comment: Great. I think I have one final question. I understand that the expectation of any random variable $X$ is $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xf(x)dx$. Because the distribution is symmetric you are able to break it up into two parts, the LHS and RHS of the distribution. So my question is how did expectation end up as $\int_0^{\infty} P[Y>t]dt$ ? I think because of this way of looking at the expectation I have been having a hard time understanding the problem.

Comment: A general formula for the expectation of a nonnegative random variable $W$ is $E[W] = \int_0^{\infty} P[W>t]dt$.  If $W$ has a PDF then this is consistent with $E[W] = \int_0^{\infty} t f_W(t)dt$.

Comment: Thanks I understood the case for the three random variables. But if I apply the exact same logic for five random variables I would still get infinite variance no?

Comment: By the same reasoning, if $Z$ is the median of 5 i.i.d. Cauchy random variables we get $$P[Z>t] \leq {5 \choose 3} P[X_1>t]^3 = O(1/t^3)$$ so $Z^+$ has finite mean and variance.

Comment: I understood for mean how it is bounded. You mentioned in the last two lines that $E[(Y^+)^2] \geq 2 \int_0^{\infty} t P[X_1>t]^2dt = \infty$ hence the variance is infinite. Isn't the same logic true for 5 IIDs?

Comment: Just apply the equality formula I give for the second moment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132196/discussion-between-gtx-oc-and-michael).

Comment: Note the following standard formulas:  Suppose $R$ is a nonnegative random variable.  Then $$R  = \int_0^R dt = \int_0^{\infty} 1\{R>t\}dt$$ $$R^2 = 2\int_0^R tdt = 2\int_0^{\infty} t 1\{R>t\}dt$$ so taking expectations gives $$ E[R] = \int_0^{\infty} E[1\{R>t\}]dt$$ $$E[R^2] = 2\int_0^{\infty} t E[1\{R>t\}]dt$$ where $E[1\{R>t\}]=P[R>t]$.